# How to un-minimize selenium window?

Tags: python, selenium

There are tons of guides that show how to minimize browser window opened with Selenium. But I can't find any guide for un-minimize minimized window.

- I don't want to maximize the window. Instead, I want to restore at the same size.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is this:

```py
#make this variable before minimize:
handle_of_the_window = driver.current_window_handle
driver.minimize_window()

# your code


# now switch to that window and restore it
driver.switch_to.window(handle_of_the_window)
driver.set_window_rect(0, 0)
```